# Nextjs component with data coming from an API

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I need to create some cards that will have the content based on data returned from an API. However, I haven't found ways to do this when the website is being rendered, and the ones I've tried haven't worked. The div will contain the cards, but how can i pass the "packages" as properties to the component?

```
import { GetPackages, SetWebstoreIdentifier } from "tebex_headless";
SetWebstoreIdentifier("tv5y-6b682b0fe1661c45c836b56fb7244d3d840d18c7");

async function test() {
  const packages = await GetPackages();
  console.log(packages[0]);
}
test();
export function CardBox() {
  return (
    <div
      className="
      grid gap-6 place-items-center
      sm:grid-cols-2
      lgg:grid-cols-4
    "
    ></div>
  );
}
```

I tried to use an

`{Array.from({length:4}).map(() => { <Card //The values returned from the package would come here /> })}`

but, in the ways I've tried, I couldn't pass the package values into the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Next.js *(App Router)* you can create `async` component (only works with `server components` i.e. not using `"use client"`).

so you can fetch your data directly in your component then render it as you like.

*(the below code assumes that `const packages = await GetPackages();` will return data in `array-like` format)*

```
import { GetPackages, SetWebstoreIdentifier } from "tebex_headless";
SetWebstoreIdentifier("tv5y-6b682b0fe1661c45c836b56fb7244d3d840d18c7");

export default async function CardBox() {
  const packages = await GetPackages();
  // parse your data if needed
  const data = await packages.json();
  console.log(data) // check your data your data
  return (
    {data.map(item => (
    <div
      key={item.id}
      className="
      grid gap-6 place-items-center
      sm:grid-cols-2
      lgg:grid-cols-4">
    {item?.name}
    </div>))}
  );
}
```

Comment: You’re most welcome, glad to know it helps. However, I prefer calling me a master, expert or professional rather than a god (I know you don’t mean it exactly)